# Notifications in Xcode not coming up

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to add a notification to my code so that when a button is pressed, a user is saved to a database and a notification pops up saying that the user has been successfully saved to the database. I have checked my code, but it's still not working. No errors are coming up, but neither are any notifications. I'm trying to create a small banner at the top of the screen saying "Customer saved to database".

Here's my code; if you could spot any errors or suggest how to fix it, I would be really grateful!

Using Xcode 8.2.1. and Objective C

in AppDelegate.m:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application     didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(nonnull UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings{}
```

in NewCustomerViewController.m:

```
@interface NewCustomerViewController(){NSUserDefaults *defaults;}
```

in the viewdidload:

```
defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge| UIUserNotificationTypeSound| UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];
```

and finally, in my IBaction for the button that saves customers:

```
[defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"notificationIsActive"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.fireDate = 0;
    //Enter the time here in seconds.
    localNotification.alertBody= @"Customer Saved to Database";
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    //localNotification.repeatInterval= NSCalendarUnitDay;//NSCalendarUnitMinute; //Repeating instructions here.
    localNotification.soundName= UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

Thanks again!

Comment: What iOS version you are using? Your app is open and in foreground?

Comment: My iOS Deployment Target is 8.0, is that what you mean? I have the app open in a simulator on my desktop

Comment: You can't display a local notification if your app is in the foreground (unless you simulate it using a UIView that you make to look like one) unless you target iOS 10.0. Is there any reason to target iOS 8.0? There's only about 5% or so of users using iOS 8.

Comment: I think that is open, ok the target is 8 but you can only show notification with the app open in iOS 10 and above, try to put a delay for the notification and put the in background and see if works

Comment: It works when the app is not in the foreground on both ios 8 and 10 (I added a delay to test, and it worked). Is there any easy way to get it to come up with the app in the foreground? -- And I was trying to make my app accessible to more by targeting iOS 8, but if the numbers are that low, I can put the target up! (It's for my A level so I needed to make it accessible - I can talk about the low numbers using ios 8 though)

Comment: Its very easy with iOS 10, for iOS 8 you will have to create a UIView and design it to be the same size and shape and appearance etc. as a notification so its an unnecessary hassle.

Comment: Do you know how to/ of any tutorials explaining how to get the notification to come up when the app is in the foreground? (currently it doesn't work in the foreground, only when the app is in the background) I can't seem to find any help on it! Thanks :)

Comment: @CharlotteMallory iOS 8 _does not_ supports showing up of a local notification when the app is in foreground mode.

Comment: What about for iOS 10?

Answer (score 0):

The way you use to work with Local Notification in iOS 9 and below is completely different in iOS 10.
Below is code for local notification :

**Objective-C :**

```
1. In App-delegate.h file use @import UserNotifications;
2. App-delegate should conform to UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate protocol
3. In didFinishLaunchingOptions use below code :

UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
[center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionBadge | UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert)
                          completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            if (!error) {
                     NSLog(@"request authorization succeeded!");
                     [self showAlert];
                              }
                          }];

-(void)showAlert {
    UIAlertController *objAlertController = [UIAlertControlleralertControllerWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"show an alert!"preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    
    UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction
                                   actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                                   style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                       NSLog(@"Ok clicked!");
                                   }];
    [objAlertController addAction:cancelAction];
    
    
    [[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:0] rootViewController] presentViewController:objAlertController animated:YEScompletion:^{
        
    }];
    
}
4. Now create a button in any view controller and in IBAction use below code :
UNMutableNotificationContent *objNotificationContent = [[UNMutableNotificationContent alloc] init];
    objNotificationContent.title = [NSStringlocalizedUserNotificationStringForKey:@“Notification!”arguments:nil];
    objNotificationContent.body = [NSStringlocalizedUserNotificationStringForKey:@“This is local notification message!“
                                                         arguments:nil];
    objNotificationContent.sound = [UNNotificationSounddefaultSound];
    
    /// 4. update application icon badge number
    objNotificationContent.badge = @([[UIApplicationsharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1);
    
    // Deliver the notification in five seconds.
    UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger *trigger = [UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger
                                                  triggerWithTimeInterval:10.f repeats:NO];       
    
    UNNotificationRequest *request = [UNNotificationRequestrequestWithIdentifier:@“ten”
                                                                          content:objNotificationContent trigger:trigger];
    /// 3. schedule localNotification
    UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCentercurrentNotificationCenter];
    [center addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@“Local Notification succeeded“);
        }
  else {
      NSLog(@“Local Notification failed“);
  }
    }];
```

You can refer apple reference document [https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications for UserNotification](http://You%20can%20refer%20apple%20reference%20document%20https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications%20for%20UserNotification.).